# cmd/bat file not running properly if ran as administrator from external drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, external, drive

I have made a simple batch file to copy a file from its folder to Windows 10 Program Files folder. The problem is if I run the file with right click run as administrator from any drive in the main hard disk it runs properly. But if I run it from an external USB drive with right click run as administrator, CMD gets flashed for a second but it does not even pause. Neither the file gets copied. If I run cmd file from an already open cmd prompt with admin rights, it runs properly. If I run double click cmd file and run without administrator, the CMD stays open and says Access is Denied which should be for C://Program Files
Below is the code

```
pushd %~dp0
MD "C:\Program Files\Example Folder"
ROBOCOPY . "C:\Program Files\Example Folder" "Example File.ext"
popd
PAUSE
```

I have tried XCOPY and COPY as well.

Comment: Run the command prompt as an administrator and run the script to see what error it gives.

Comment: It might help to show the output of `cacls` for the mentioned directories / files

Comment: I guess when right-clicking and running as admin from external drive, the admin simply does not see the drive (letter); unfortunately I have no idea right now to overcome that...